# C# mvc2 client side form validation with xval, prevent post

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

I'm using [xval](http://xval.codeplex.com/) to use client side validation in my asp.net mvc2 web-application. Despite the errors it's giving when I enter text in a numeric field, it still tries to post the form to the database. The incorrect values are being replaced by 0 and saved to the database. But instead it shouldn't even be possible to try and submit the form. Can anyone help me out here?

I've set the attributes as below:

```
[Property]
[ShowColumnInCrud(true, label = "FromPriceInCents")]
[Required]
//[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
public virtual Int32 FromPriceInCents{ get; set; }
```

The controller catching the request looks as below; I'm getting no errors in this part.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[Transaction]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public override ActionResult Create()
{
  //some foo happens
}
```

My view looks like below:

```
<div class="label"><label for="Price">FromPrice</label></div>
<div class="field">
<%= Html.TextBox("FromPriceInCents")%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("product.FromPriceInCents")%></div>
```

And at the end of the view i have the following rule which in html code generates the correct validation rules

```
<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Product>("Product") %>
```

I hope someone can helps me out with this issue, thanks in advance!

EDIT: 19th April
I just found out that there is a normal button with being used instead of an input type="Button" Could this be the issue?

```
<button class="save" type="submit" name="save"><span>Opslaan</span></button>
```

Comment: Why is your ValidationMessage("product.FromPriceInCents") but your textbox uses "FromPriceInCents"? This seems suspect. Is there any reason you aren't using the strongly typed helpers? ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.FromPriceInCents)

Comment: I changed the textboxes and validationmessages to strongly typed helpers. But this change doesn't affect the validation, nevertheless good tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

[How to use the jQuery Validation plugin with metadata, jQuery Forms and xVal together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996125/how-to-use-jquery-validation-plugin-with-metadata-and-the-jquery-forms-plugin-wi)

Comment: This was the push i needed in the right direction! The jquery validate function did the trick. The form was loaded with jquery and after submitting the validation wasn't correctly handled

Answer (score 2):

My first and main concern here would be: why is your app saving the values in the database in the first place? While xVal is a good way to make the application user friendly, you still HAVE to do server side validation. If you don't validate your data on the server - you have a masive security hole! Try checking if the ModelState.IsValid in your controller before saving the values.

Now, from what I see you're registering the xVal validation using

```
<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Product>("Product") %>
```

The way it works is it enables client side validation for all controls prefixed with "Product". Your textbox on the other hand has an id of **FromPriceInCents**

So the solution here would be to do this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FromPriceInCents")%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("FromPriceInCents")%>

<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Product>() %>
```

**UPD3**
I updated the post. Fixed the code so that the prefix is not used.

Also, I compiled a working solution that contains a working solution. List, Edit, Create page, string and int properties, and xVal validation.

```
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1,50)]
    public int PriceInCents { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and on the view

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PriceInCents) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriceInCents) %>
```

Here's the download link.. Check it out and tell me if it works
http://www.flexlabs.org/download/xValTest

Comment: Thanks for the good response, i'll try your solution and let you know. You're right about the server side validation, i indeed still need to fix this.

Comment: I tried your solution by adding the prefix to the textbox. But then the validation doesn't work at all. When i use it like this;

    <%= Html.TextBox("FromPriceInCents")%>

    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("product.FromPriceInCents")%>

    <%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Product>("product") %>

The validation is showing me errors when i enter text in a box expecting numbers. But when i try to submit the page it is still doing a postback, something which i don't expect and want it to do.

Got serverside validation working now with Modelstate.IsValid

Comment: Ah yes, that's because the Create method could not puck up the values from the form values.. I updated the post with an example

Comment: @Artion thanks for the quick response, i tried both your suggestion but it doesn't work :( I found out that where using a button to submit the form, so i updated the question with it. Could this have something to do with the issue?

Comment: Updated the post with a more correct example + an example project download.. definitely working :)

Comment: Thanks Artiom! Your example works just as my application should. Gonna try and fix the problem using your example. I'll let you know!

Comment: Got it working! I debugged it all the way so it was equal to your example. The only difference left was that i was using a form which was loaded with jquery, this because i've got a tab oriented interface. Because of this the client side validation wasn't correctly called when submitting the form. So i wrote a little javascript to call this function and this fixed the problem. I removed the prefixes as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the Range attribute commented out? With the properties you have specified as long as anything is entered in the textbox it should pass client side validation.

Comment: The range attribute is an an test. But i'll try putting it back on and see what happens.

Comment: OK i tried it, the client side validation is giving this error;

Please enter a value between 1 and 2147483647.

But in firebug i can see the page is still trying to do an postback, but it returns the error below;

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Try having your Create action take the object type like this
public ActionResult Create(ObjectType newObject)

Comment: The controller is already taking the following parameters

public override ActionResult Create(Guid pageId, Guid pluginInstanceId, Product entity, FormCollection collection)